# Cobertura custom filters

Tags: cobertura

I'm using Cobertura in a Jenkins/Hudson server script.

I'd like to ignore certain kinds of methods/constructors from code coverage. For instance default constructors which are required to exist for things like JDO/JPA/Hibernate. Also standard getters and setters which apply no logic. These types of methods/constructors prevent me from targeting 100% code coverage.

Anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?